# Вопрос по pandas.datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Изучаю pandas и сейчас очень сильно застрял на моменте с форматированием столбца в датафрейме в нормальный формат дд/мм/гг. Собственно суть вопрос в следующем пытаюсь сделать так:

```
fins_data['Дата зачисления ДС'] = pd.to_datetime(fins_data['Дата зачисления ДС'],format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

но датафрейм как оставался с секундами, там и остается, помогите пожалуйста:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, в каком у вас изначально формате данный столбец, но судя по тому, как вы его переводите, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```
fins_data['Дата зачисления ДС'] = pd.to_datetime(fins_data['Дата зачисления ДС']).dt.date

>>>
0  2022-03-25
1  2022-03-25
2  2022-03-25
3  2022-03-25
```

либо если вам нужен определенный формат, допустим, как вы его указали, то можно следующим образом

```
df['Дата зачисления ДС'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Дата зачисления ДС']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

>>>
0  03/25/2022
1  03/25/2022
2  03/25/2022
3  03/25/2022
```

Comment: спасибо Вам большое!